# Read system call for C unix socket only returns and gets triggered when new line is detected. Is this the default behaviour?

Tags: c, tcp, system-calls, unix-socket

The sources on the Internet and books I've been reading seem to not specify exactly how the unix read system call behaves and when exactly it is triggered. They simply say that as soon as data are sent from the other end this data are available for consuming with the read and as soon as the EOF signal is received ( for example because of FIN ) the returns -1.

**1) How come that the read in this server is ONLY triggered when data are sent that include an \n new line  character ?**

**2) Why does the read get stuck if \n is not detected ?**

**3) How come that if I try to reverse the situation ( the server sends data and the client reads it this situation doesn't occur ?**

**4) Has this behaviour something to do with some TCP/IP protocol stack settings on my OS that set different behaviours when read is applied to client or server respectively?**

This is the server :

```
#define PORT 1026


int main(){


 int sockfd, connfd;
 unsigned int len;
 struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cli;


//SOCKET CREATION
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
if (sockfd == -1) {
        printf("socket creation failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }

bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr =htonl(INADDR_ANY);
servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
//BIND
if ((bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr))) != 0) {
        printf("socket bind failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
//LISTEN
if ((listen(sockfd, 5)) != 0) {
        printf("Listen failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }

for(;;){

len = sizeof(cli);

connfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&cli, &len);


if (connfd < 0) {
        printf("server accept failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }else{
        printf("New connection accepted !\n");
    }


char buffr;
int r;
while( (r=read(connfd,&buffr,sizeof(buffr))) > 0 ){
    if(buffr=='#') break;
    printf("%c",buffr);
};


close(connfd);
};

return 0;

}
```

And this is the client sending data :

```
#define PORT 1026

int main(){


int sockfd;
struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cli;
//CREATE SOCKET
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sockfd == -1) {
        printf("socket creation failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
   
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) != 0) {
        printf("connection with the server failed...\n");
        //exit(0);
    }


char s[]="Hello World !#";  // DOESN'T WORK !
/*char s[]="Hello World !#\n"; DOES WORK*/
write(sockfd,s,sizeof(s));


close(sockfd);

return 0;

}
```

I'm using Mac OS and I've also checked on the wireshark traffic and it seems there are no problems with the packets. So, what's going on here ?

Comment: A little note about your error checking: It's good that you have it (except for `read` which also need it), but you only write that there's an error, not telling what the error was. You need to check `errno` for that, and you can get a text printout using either `perror` instead of `printf`, or `printf` with `strerror`.

Comment: Side note: there is no need for a semicolon after the close brace of a loop as seen in your server code.  It is an empty statement unrelated to the loop.  If you add a semicolon after the body of an `if` statement, you can not add an `else`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in how you print the characters, not about how you receive the data.

By default, when `stdout` (where `printf` writes) is connected to an interactive terminal, it will be *line* buffered. That means all output written to `stdout` will be buffered until either one of four things happens:

1. The buffer is full
2. The buffer is explicitly flushed (with `fflush(stdout`))
3. There's a newline being written
4. The process exits

If the data you receive doesn't contain a newline, then it will be kept in the buffer and not written to the actual terminal.

The solution is simple: Write a newline, or call `fflush(stdout)`.

Comment: I tried to fflush and it seems it is working. How come that if I reverse the situation ( the server sends data and the client reads it ) this problem doesn't occur ? I'm still a little confused @Some programmer dude

Comment: @Kode1000 How do you print in the client? How are you running the client?

Comment: @ Some programmer dude The print in the client is exactly as it is in the server with the read loop and the printf inside of it. What do you mean when you say "interactive terminal" ? Why data is not buffered in the stdout when I normally use printf ? For 
 example int main(){ printf("Hello World"); return 0; } ?

Comment: @Kode1000 In that example the output *is* buffered. Try adding a short delay between the `printf` and the `return`, and run from a normal command-line environment. The buffers will be flushed as part of the program exiting. Which might also answer your question about the client program: It exits (and output is written) to quickly for you to be aware of any problems.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I tried this code : int main(){
int a=0;
printf("Hello World");
while(a<=1000000000){
if(a==1000000000){return 0;}
a++;
}
} and it behaves as you said. Could you refer me to some online sources or books that go in deep with stuff like this ? @ Some programmer dude